# Images not showing on site

Tags: python, django

I can not see the images show up as broken on my site. Here is what I tried :

1. Installed Pillow: imported it in my `models.py`.
2. Settings.py has :

   ```
   MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
   MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
   ```
3. Pictures: currently in my "media" folder which sits in my main project directory.
4. app/urls.py has `static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` and imported settings.
5. Template has `{% load static %} and {{ post.image.url }}`.
6. Collected static.
7. Made migrations.
8. Ran server :

   ```
   settings.py
   STATIC_URL = '/static/'
   STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/') 
   STATICFILES_DIRS = [
       os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'profiles/static/')
   ]
   MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
   MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

   urls.py
   from django.urls import path
   from . import views
   from django.conf import settings
   from django.conf.urls.static import static

   urlpatterns = [
       path('post/<id>/', views.post, name='post'),
       ....
       ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

   models.py
   from django.db import models
   from django.conf import settings
   from PIL import Image

   class Profile(models.Model):
       title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
       bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
       user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
   on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

       def __str__(self):
           return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

   class Post(models.Model):
       title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
       post = models.TextField(max_length=100, blank=True)
       image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', 
   upload_to='picsinposts')
       profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
   blank=True, null=True)

       def __str__(self):
           return self.title
   ```

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}    
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<html>
<body>
 <div class= "Profile">
            <h2>  {{ profile.title }}  </h2>
            <p> {{ profile.bio }} </p>
            {% if request.user == profile.user %}
             <a href="{% url 'edit_profile' id=profile.id %}"> Edit your profile! </a>
            {% endif %}
 </div>
 <br>
 {% for post in post %}
 <div class= "Posts">
  <a href="{% url 'post' id=post.id %}"> {{ post.title }} </a>
  <p> <img src="{{ post.image.url }}", style= "width:100px;"/> </p>
  <a href="{% url 'follow' id=profile.id %}"> Follow Profile! </a>
```

[Where my pictures live currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzkIN.jpg)

What am I missing?

Comment: That's your app urls. The static URLs need to be added to the main project URLs. (Although note this is for development only.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your static url need to be in your project's urls.py.
Remove this form `app/urls.py` and place into your `project's` urls.py instead:

project/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
...... ..] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```